# MongoDB update latest subdocument

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

here is my mongo document..

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a69d0acb76d1c2e08e4ccd8"),
    "subscriptions" : [ 
        {
            "sub_id" : "5a56fd399dd78e33948c9b8e",
            "invoice_id" : "5a56fd399dd78e33948c9b8d"
        }, 
        {
            "sub_id" : "5a56fd399dd78e33948c9b8e"
        }
    ]
}
```

i want to update and upsert invoice_id into last element of sub-array..
i have tried..
                  sort: {$natural: -1},
     subscription.$.invoice

what i want it to be is....

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a69d0acb76d1c2e08e4ccd8"),
    "subscriptions" : [ 
        {
            "sub_id" : "5a56fd399dd78e33948c9b8e",
            "invoice_id" : "5a56fd399dd78e33948c9b8d"
        }, 
        {
            "sub_id" : "5a56fd399dd78e33948c9b8e",
            "invoice_id" : "5a56fd399dd78e33948c9b8f"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: May I ask why you chose that data structure? Sometimes when a data structure proves unwieldy for what you want to do, it pays to rethink the data structure.

Semantically speaking, every element / object in an array should have the *same* data structure. That doesn't mean that every object should have all possible properties, but that all properties should be allowed.

In your case, that means every array element *should* be able to have an invoice_id. If that's not the case, then the invoice_id should be moved out of the array.

Comment: In my case i am performing..   1. Add subscription_id into subscriptions then 2. Add Invoice Details into INVOICE collection...then 3.Add newly added invoice record's _id into newly added subscription i.e. in step 1.

Comment: Can each subscription have an invoice then? Or only the latest subscription? Also, in your example, I noticed the sub_id is the same for all elements. Is that truly the case, or just a quick cut/paste for the purposes of this example?If the sub_id's are indeed all the same, then you should pull it out of the array and just store it as a property of the parent, and then the array is just an array of invoices.

Comment: OTOH, if the sub_id's are different, I would highly recommend you add the invoice_id by first finding the array element with the correct sub_id. Simply adding it to the last element can introduce race conditions (e.g. if two subs are added simultaneously, you can't depend on which one is 'last' in the array)

Comment: Also, if you already have the subscription_id, why not add the Invoice Details to the INVOICE collection *first*, which would allow you to get the invoice_id, then you can push an object onto the array with both the sub_id and the invoice_id at once. This will give you better performance (you're only updating the subscriptions array once), and more importantly, eliminate race conditions (since the entire object is added in one operation).

Comment: Actually, every subdoc will have sub_id and invoice_id...there may happen that some of the subdoc has same sub_id but there will be different invoice_id for sure. And invoce_id refers to the payment details.Previously it was like invoice will have user's _id and user will have invoice's _id therefore i had to first insert user record or invoice and insert their _id's in one another.Finally i got the way to do the same by firstly inserting invoice detail first and then subscription record. I have changed the way according to your suggestion. THANK YOU MAN!!!

Comment: No problem. I wrote up the recommended solution as an answer. If this is what you ended up doing, do you mind marking my response as the answer to close the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there are ways to get the last array element, like Saravana shows in her answer, I don't recommend doing it that way because it introduces race conditions. For example, if two subs are added simultaneously, you can't depend on which one is 'last' in the array.

If an invoice_id has to be tied to a specific sub_id, then it's far better to query and find that specific element in the array, then add the invoice_id to it.

In the comments, the OP indicated that the current order of operations is 1) add sub_id, 2) insert the invoice record into the INVOICE collection and get the invoice_id, 3) add the invoice_id into the new subscription.

However, if you already have the sub_id, then it's better to re-order your operations this way: 1) insert the invoice record and get the invoice_id 2) add *both* sub_id and invoice_id with a single operation.

Doing this improves performance (eliminates the second update operation), but more importantly, eliminates race conditions because you're adding both sub_id and invoice_id at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

we can get the document and update last element by index

```
> var doc = db.sub.findOne({"_id" : ObjectId("5a69d0acb76d1c2e08e4ccd8")})

> if ( doc.subscriptions.length - 1 >= 0 ) 
    doc.subscriptions[doc.subscriptions.length-1].invoice_id="5a56fd399dd78e33948c9b8f"

> db.sub.update({_id:doc._id},doc)
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

or write an aggregation pipeline to form the document and use it for update

```
db.sub.aggregate(
    [
        {$match : { "_id" : ObjectId("5a69d0acb76d1c2e08e4ccd8") }},
        {$addFields : { last : { $subtract : [{$size : "$subscriptions"},1]}}},
        {$unwind : { path :"$subscriptions" , includeArrayIndex : "idx"}},
        {$project : { "subscriptions.sub_id" : 1, 
                    "subscriptions.invoice_id" : {
                        $cond : {
                            if: { $eq: [ "$idx", "$last" ] },
                            then: "5a56fd399dd78e33948c9b8f",
                            else: "$$REMOVE"
                        }
                    }
                }
        },
        {$group : {_id : "$_id", subscriptions : {$push : "$subscriptions"}}}
    ]
).pretty()
```

result doc

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a69d0acb76d1c2e08e4ccd8"),
    "subscriptions" : [
        {
            "sub_id" : "5a56fd399dd78e33948c9b8e"
        },
        {
            "sub_id" : "5a56fd399dd78e33948c9b8e",
            "invoice_id" : "5a56fd399dd78e33948c9b8f"
        }
    ]
}
```